# VBA, Advanced filter workbook, populate into common columns across worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have workbook A with many columns and headers, I would like to separate this data and populate into workbook B based on header name(workbook B has 4 sheets of different pre populated column headers)

1)  Workbook A (many columns), filter  for all its unique values in col 'AN' (ie. col AN  has 20 unique values but ~3000 rows each for each unique set).

2) There is workbook B, with pre populated columns in 4 sheets, not all are the same headers as in workbook A. Here is where the unique values from col AN from workbook A with their respective records will be populated, one after the other.

The goal here is to populate these 4 sheets with data from Workbook A, sorting by each unique column AN value, with its records into the prepopulated workbook B.

This code so far just filters my main 'AN' column uniquely and just gets unique values, I need unique values along with records.

```
Sub Sort()


Dim wb As Workbook, fileNames As Object, errCheck As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wks As Worksheet, wksSummary As Worksheet
    Dim y As Range, intRow As Long, i As Integer

Dim r As Range, lr As Long, myrg As Range, z As Range
    Dim boolWritten As Boolean, lngNextRow As Long
    Dim intColNode As Integer, intColScenario As Integer
    Dim intColNext As Integer, lngStartRow As Long
    Dim lngLastNode As Long, lngLastScen As Long


                                 ' Finds column AN , header named 'first name'
                intColScenario = 0
                On Error Resume Next
                intColScenario = WorksheetFunction.Match("First name", .Rows(1), 0)
                On Error GoTo 0

                If intColScenario > 0 Then
                     ' Only action if there is data in column E
                    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(intColScenario)) > 1 Then
                       lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, intColScenario).End(xlUp).Row


                         ' Copy unique values from the formula column to the 'Unique data' sheet, and write sheet & file details
                        .Range(.Cells(1, intColScenario), .Cells(lr, intColScenario)).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, , r, True
                        r.Offset(0, -2).Value = ws.Name
                        r.Offset(0, -3).Value = ws.Parent.Name



                         ' Delete the column header copied to the list
                        r.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                        boolWritten = True
                    End If
                End If


                 'I need to take the rest of the records with this though. 

' Reset system settings
With Application
   .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   .ScreenUpdating = True
   .Visible = True
End With
End Sub
```

**Adding sample pictures**

Workbook A sample, I want to unique filter the 'job column' to get all like records together:

[image]

Workbook sample B,
Sheet 1 (note there will be multiple sheets).
As you can see workbook A has been sorted by the 'job' column.

[image]

Comment: not sure to catch how/what rows are to be filtered and copied to workbook B worksheets. please attach some examples of workbooks/worksheets involved and before/after scenarios

Comment: @user3598756 , Hi I updated with some samples, 2nd pic is the desired result, but across multiple worksheets, (the headers will be pre populated)

Comment: Have you explored Pivot Tables?

Comment: Hi  Alan. No I haven't,  not sure how that would work as I need to see which column headers from workbook A match other headers from 4 other sheets , and see where the gaps are . I'm open to further explanation though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the following code:

edited to account for workbook "B" worksheets headers in row 2 (instead of row 1 as per OP example)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim dsRng As Range
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String

    Set dsRng = Workbooks("A").Worksheets("ShtA").Range("A1").CurrentRegion '<--| set your entire data set range in workbook "A" worksheet "ShtA" (change "A" and "ShtA" to your actual names)
    dsRng.Sort key1:=dsRng.Range("AN1"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes '<--| sort data set range on its 40th column (which is "AN", beginning it from column "A")

    With Workbooks("B") '<--| refer "B" workbook
        For Each sht In .Worksheets '<--| loop through its worksheets
            GetCorrespondingColumns dsRng, sht, AShtColsList, BShtColsList '<--| build lists of corresponding columns indexes in both workbooks
            CopyColumns dsRng, sht, AShtColsList, BShtColsList '<--| copy listed columns between workbooks
        Next sht
    End With
End Sub

Sub GetCorrespondingColumns(dsRng As Range, sht As Worksheet, AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String)
    Dim f As Range, c As Range
    Dim iElem As Long

    AShtColsList = "" '<--| initialize workbook "A" columns indexes list
    BShtColsList = "" '<--| initialize workbook "B" current sheet columns indexes list
    For Each c In Sht.Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) '<--| loop through workbook "B" current sheet headers in row 2     *******
        Set f = dsRng.Rows(1).Find(what:=c.value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) '<--| look up data set headers row for workbook "B" current sheet current column header
        If Not f Is Nothing Then '<--| if it's been found ...
            BShtColsList = BShtColsList & c.Column & "," '<--| ...update workbook "B" current sheet columns list with current header column index
            AShtColsList = AShtColsList & f.Column & "," '<--| ...update workbook "A" columns list with corresponding found header column index
        End If
    Next c
End Sub

Sub CopyColumns(dsRng As Range, sht As Worksheet, AShtColsList As String, BShtColsList As String)
    Dim iElem As Long
    Dim AShtColsArr As Variant, BShtColsArr As Variant

    If AShtColsList <> "" Then '<--| if any workbook "B" current sheet header has been found in workbook "A" data set headers
        BShtColsArr = Split(Left(BShtColsList, Len(BShtColsList) - 1), ",") '<--| build an array out of workbook "B" current sheet columns indexes list
        AShtColsArr = Split(Left(AShtColsList, Len(AShtColsList) - 1), ",") '<--| build an array out of workbook "A" corresponding columns indexes list
        For iElem = 0 To UBound(AShtColsArr) '<--| loop through workbook "A" columns indexes array (you could have used workbook "A" corresponding columns indexes list as well)
            Intersect(dsRng, dsRng.Columns(CLng(AShtColsArr(iElem)))).Copy Sht.Cells(2, CLng(BShtColsArr(iElem))) '<--| copy data set current column into workbook "B" current sheet corresponding column starting from row 2     *******  
        Next iElem
    End If
End Sub
```

and should really need to have each unique name rows set in workbook "B" sheets separated by a blank row, you can write a quite simple `SubSeparateRowsSet()` and call it right after `CopyColumns()` call in `main()`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your comments are very helpful! getting an error on       .. 'For Each c In sht.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)'   No Cells were found..

Comment: are headers _constant_ (i.e not resulting from formulas) _text_ (i.e not numbers) values? are they in row 1?

Comment: Headers between the sheets of workbookB are constant, they have text but may have #'s  at the end of them.. They will be in the 2nd row. Some columns are skipped and left blank.

Comment: Headers in row 2... That was not what you had in your code shown in your question... Any how my code is much commented so find the statement where workbook B worksheets row 1 is being searched and change it to point to row 2

Comment: Sorry my example is row 1, my actual data that I did not post is in row 2.  I was testing my example posted above and get the error still. The code does stop at the line stated above, but it seems to do some of the work when i exist break mode.

Comment: Too vague a clue to build an answer on. update your question posting the minimum _environment_ (data structure, names) that reproduce the error you're experiencing. BTW I tested my solution with your posted data before answering

Comment: Okay, I got it to work. Seems like every sheet in workbookB needs to have a header and cant be blank (ie the default has 3 sheets needed to fill them all with headers).  Is there a way around this ?

Comment: or atleast choose the sheets wanted

Comment: You are changing question setting at every step. Please accept my solution as answer and make a new post with new issues

Comment: Having trouble searching and putting the data under row 2. Even after changing the 'Set f = dsRng.Rows(1).Find(what:=c.value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)' to 2.

Comment: Because it deletes row one, and seems to move up and then populate the data.

Comment: to account for workbook "B" worksheets headers in row 2 (instead of 1) you have to change row index in the statement `For Each c In Sht.Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues) ` which is the line by which to (as clearly commented) _"loop through workbook "B" current sheet columns"_. Then, in sub `CopyColumns` you also have to change the code line that writes data _"into workbook "B" current sheet corresponding column".  See edited code, with edited lines marked by asterisks at the far right

Comment: Thanks! marked as correct. A question, if you want to check for multiple rows in Workbook B, ie. instead of just looking to row 2, we check rows 2 and 3 for that col in workbook A?